# Convert text file into list

Tags: python, list

I would like to parse every line of a text file, each of which look similar to this:

```
New Mexico,Santa Fe
Alabama,Montgomery
```

I would like to parse every line, so that I end up with this:

```
states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas']
cities = ['Montgomery', 'Juneau', 'Phoenix', 'Little Rock']
```

The contents of the text file is already stored in a function: `f.read()` and is defined by:

```
#module imports
import sys
import random

fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have for this? Please indicate which areas are giving you difficulty.

Comment: Also, your subject line is a bit confusing. You say dictionary (meaning python `dict`?) but you show two lists. Give us some code and then we can proceed.

Comment: Code that does what? @idjaw

Comment: This site is for people with specific coding problems. You need to open the file, read the lines and split them into the lists. That's the code we need to see.

Comment: I pass in the filename as an argument. This is the code that prints all of the lines: `#module imports
import sys
import random

fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())`

Comment: Where do `'Juneau'` or `'Phoenix'` come from?

Comment: From the text file, each line is formatted like `state,city` @KevinGuan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can do it like this:

```
import sys
states = []
cities = []
fname = sys.argv[1]
f = open(fname, 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip() # This will remove all the whitespaces at the end of the line
    line = line.split(',')
    states.append(line[0])
    cities.append(line[1])

print states
print cities
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this helpful?

```
>>> with open('file') as f:
...     text = [i.strip() for i in f]
...     
... 
>>> text
['New Mexico,Santa Fe', 'Alabama,Montgomery']
>>> states = []
>>> cities = []
>>> for i in text:
...     states.append(i.split(',')[0])
...     cities.append(i.split(',')[1])
...     
... 
>>> states
['New Mexico', 'Alabama']
>>> cities
['Santa Fe', 'Montgomery']
>>>
```

Comment: You could make a small optimization in your code by only performing the `split` once.

Answer (score 1):

First convert it to a dictionary. Then one list is the `keys` of the dictionary and the other list is the `values` of the dictionary.

Also don't forget to check the `sys.argv` length before using it.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('must provide filename')
    exit()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    d = dict(reversed(line.strip().split(',')) for line in f)

    cities = list(d.keys())
    states = list(d.values())

print('cities = %r' % cities)
print('states = %r' % states)
```

I added the `reversed` as it makes more sense to have the city names as the key and the state name as the value.